# Sign Up Users in Bulk - Parse Platform

Tags: parse-platform

I'm creating an app in iOS using Parse where a district administrator would bulk create accounts for all students in the district using their student information system data.

I'm wondering if any method exists where a bulk number of accounts can be created? I'm aware that I can setup a for-in statement to make them all one-by-one using `signUpInBackground()`, but this method causes the current user to be logged out and the newly created user to be logged in... thus losing the district administrator session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said `signUpInBackground()` does change the current user of the app, which is true for all signup and login methods as stated in [docs](https://docs.parseplatform.org/ios/guide/#current-user):

> Whenever you use any signup or login methods, the user is cached on disk.

Solving this from client side probably wouldn't be the right approach.

The right solution for this would be usage of cloud code. We could start with creation of a cloud function, which would take list of users and generate `Parse.User` for every record in that list. But when having enough big data inputs, we could start running into timeout problems, because the time required to save all the records would be longer than the maximum reserved time for cloud code function execution. This would obviously depend on the server's configuration and available resources, but in general it is recommended to keep cloud functions reasonably short and efficient to ensure good performance.

Taking into an account that this will be bulk creation of records we need something that support [long running tasks](https://docs.parseplatform.org/cloudcode/guide/#cloud-jobs).

> Sometimes you want to execute long running functions, and you don’t want to wait for the response. Cloud Jobs are meant for just that.

The right choice for signing up users in bulk would be cloud jobs. Steps for achieving your goal could be:

1. Define cloud function which gets as input array of users. This function will invoke cloud job and forward the array of users to it.

```javascript
Parse.Cloud.define('invokeCreateUsersJob', (req) => {
  const users = req.params.users
  const isArray = Array.isArray(users)

  // Return error in case users parameter is not an array
  if (!isArray) {
    return new Error('users paramater must be an array type')
  }

  // Invoke cloud job with users array
  return Parse.Cloud.startJob('createUsersJob', { users })
})
```

If everything goes as planned `invokeCreateUsersJob` function will return job status ID which can be later used to check status of job with call to `Parse.Cloud.getJobStatus(jobStatusId)`.

2. Define cloud job which will map users array to `Parse.User` objects. Created users can then be signed up in batches. There is a great [post about batch insertion in parse](https://community.parseplatform.org/t/guide-a-more-stable-way-for-mass-save-operations-than-parse-object-saveall/3407) and why `Parse.Object.saveAll()` may not be the right choice. Here is my solution derived from the post mentioned earlier, but reworked for signing up user.

```javascript
Parse.Cloud.job('createUsersJob', async (req) => {
  
  const users = req.params.users

  let parseUsers = users.map((user) => {
    // Map user fields to Parse.User object
    const parseUser = new Parse.User()
    parseUser.set('username', user.username)
    parseUser.set('password', user.password)
    parseUser.set('email', user.email)
    return parseUser
  })

  // Decide what number of users you want to save at a time
  const batchSize = 100
  let batches = []

  // Loop through the parse users
  // adding batch size to index
  // on every repetition
  for (let i = 0; i < parseUsers.length; i += batchSize) {
    // Take a slice of array as a batch
    const batch = parseUsers.slice(i, i + batchSize)
    // and map items of batch to promises
    const promises = batch.map( (pu) => pu.signUp(null, { useMasterKey: true }) )
    batches.push(promises)
  }

  // Now await every batch
  // before proceeding to next one
  for (const batch of batches) {
    await Promise.all(batch)
  }

  return "Number of users successfully saved: " + parseUsers.length
})
```

And there you have it, solution for bulk sign up of users on parse server that can now be used from any client capable of communicating with parse.

Call to cloud functions can be made with built-in methods of Parse SDK or via http request. On how to make this on iOS read Parse SDK [guide](https://docs.parseplatform.org/ios/guide/#use-cloud-code).